# Regex capturing sub groups with exact and partial matches

Tags: java, regex

I have

```
input string : 
$data.store.author_handle.name0_handle[*].some.min()
regex :
^\$([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(.[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+[\[\*0-9\]]*[.a-zA-Z_0-9]*)(.[min\(\)]*$)
```

So I get groups as follows

1. data
2. .store.author_handle.name0_handle[*].some.min
3. ()

Where as I want to capture as below

1. data
2. .store.author_handle.name0_handle[*].some
3. .min()

Please note input can take the forms

```
$<literal>.<json path> <aggregator function>
<aggregator function> is optional and can be min/max/avg 
<literal> : ([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)
```

Json path is any that is allowed by https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Comment: Your input is not clear to me.  In the first type of input, you might do well to split on `.`.  As for the second type, regex does not handle XML well.

Comment: Input is a sequence $<literal><json path><aggregator function>

Comment: The issue that I am facing is that json path regex is overalapping with aggregator function regex.

Comment: Try [`^\$(\w+)(\.[\w.]+\[[*0-9]\][.\w]*)(\.min\(\))$`](https://regex101.com/r/qK7sM8/1)

Comment: It does not matches with something like $data.store.price.min() but works like charm with $data.store[9].price.min() -- the part [*] or [0-9] is optional .. can you make it work

Comment: This is the closest I have managed with your help Wiktor, can you make it work !! Will be of great help , thanks a ton

Comment: try **[this](https://regex101.com/r/iX0rA6/1)**

Comment: or **[this](https://regex101.com/r/iX0rA6/3)**

Comment: works if aggregation function is added like .min but not if I dont provide aggregation function like $data.[*].author

Comment: aggreagator function is optional as you said..and can be `min/max/avg ` as mentioned

Comment: if you don't want to make it optional, remove `?` from last

Comment: Looks like theres some misunderstanding , If you were to try $data.[*].author on link you have posted earlier , you will know what I mean .. @rock321987

Comment: so what do you expect the output then for that input?

Comment: aggregation function to be in group3 if they exist , every thing starting from from first occurrence of '.' till before aggregator function should be in group 2. Every thing from start to first '.' should be in group 1

Comment: you can check **[second link](https://regex101.com/r/iX0rA6/4)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex

```
^\$([\w]+)(\..+?)((?:\.(?:min|max|avg)\(\))?$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX0rA6/6)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #start of string
\$ #Match $ literally

( #Start of 1st capturing group
  [\w]+ #Match characters in set [A-Za-z0-9_] at least once(you can also use [^.]+)
) #End of 1st capturing group

( #Start of 2nd capturing group
  \. #Match . literally
  .+? #Match lazily till next condition is met
) #End of 2nd capturing group

( #Start of 3rd capturing group
  (?: #Non capturing group
    \. #Match . literally
      (?: #Non capturing group
         min|max|avg #Match any from min,max or avg
      )
    \(\) #Match () literally
  )? #As mentioned, this all can be optional(aggregation part)
  $ #End of string(Kept here so that if nothing matches 0 sized string is returned instead of null)
) #End of 3rd capturing group
```

**or**

```
^\$([\w]+)(\..+?)((?:\.(?:(?:\w+)\(\)))?$)
```

for generalized aggregation function

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/jh8NZF)**

Comment: Can you briefly explain how you arrived at the regex pattern ? It will be of great help to all the readers of this post @rock321987